# "Null Pointer Exception" questions closed as duplicates

Tags: discussion, tags, duplicate-questions, canonical

Whenever someone posted a question attached  with `nullpointerException` logcat, the question will be down-voted and marked as duplicated, and soon it will be closed.

I admit this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is a very informative post as it helps us to know more about `Null Pointer Exception` but some of the questions will not be solved by just reading on this post.

Since the question will be marked as duplicated, why it still need to have a tag for `nullpointexception` ? Before downvote or marked it as duplicated, did you guys really read through what are the problem facing by the OP?  Did the answer provided really can solve the issue facing by the OP?

Comment: So, what are you exactly asking / suggesting? Removal of that tag? Asking if we read the questions? Asking what to do if a question't incorrectly closed?

Comment: PSA: posting a meta question with the exact title of a main site question is not the wisest thing to do.

Comment: @Cerbrus at least read the question before mark as duplicates :)

Comment: You didn't answer me. What are you asking in this meta question? The assumption no-one reads a question before close-voting it is borderline insulting.

Comment: A null pointer exception is a trivial error that is usually easily debugged, traced and fixed, and so it's of little importance.  It's also a source of huge annoyance to SO contributors who continually have to go over the same ground.

Comment: @Cerbrus I just answered you ..I wrote at this because my post get a downvote not even 20 sec..

Comment: @Cerbrus - that's how it works now.  Insulting the skilled and experienced SO contributors is just fine, but pull up a 'member for today' poster with a bad question and you will get flagged, emailed as 'hostile' and suspended for a month.

Comment: @Hoo You haven't exlained why closing your question for the right canonical question would be wrong, or in any way inferior to answering it yet again. Alternatively, explain why that's not a dupe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> some of the questions will not be solved by just reading on this post

No single problem can be solved by reading alone, the reader also has to apply the debugging hints provided in that post and debug their code themselves.

Stack Overflow is a site where programming enthusiasts can share interesting programming problems. A NullPointerException/NullReferenceException is not interesting at all, and the core problem always is the same: trying to dereference a null pointer.

People who post null-dereferencing problems generally simply lack the basic debugging skills necessary to find and solve this common issue. It is not SO's place to teach them those debugging skills nor to do the debugging for them. The canonical questions on this subject are great starting points to figuring this exception out for yourself, meanwhile improving your debugging skills.

Such questions are of no interest whatsoever to other users (previously "Too Localized"), hence not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

As for [your specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852604/failed-to-implement-a-search-widget) that triggered this question, paraphrased:

> `searchView.setSearchableInfo()` throws this exception

Means your actual question is:

> Why doesn't `SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();` find my view?

That's why [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explicitly states: **Search, and research**. Your actual question isn't *"Why do I get a NullPointerException"*, and the answer to that question (*"Something is null"*) isn't going to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Given all the nasty, intermittent, difficult bugs that afflict software devvelopment, I cannot understand the coumn-inches attached to null pointers, in any language.

Comment: OMG!!  A NULL POINTER!!  MY LIFE IS OVER!!